# What is the optimum number of elements for a merge-insertion sort to begin insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, insertion-sort

I am currently learning about algorithms and came across this hybrid merge-insertion sort algorithm. If given a merge-insertion sort algorithm such as,

```
mergesort(arr, start, end)
  if (end - start <= X)
    perform insertionsort
  else if (end - start > X)
    mergesort(arr, start, mid)
    mergesort(arr, mid+1, end)
    merge(arr, start, end)
```

how do I find the optimal level of X for this hybrid algorithm to outperform a normal merge sort algorithm?

Comment: (See also: [Analyzing Hybrid Merge and Insertion Sort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143529/19966).) Should depend - balanced merges in the *merge* part, making good use of the memory hierarchy in *insertion sort*.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal number for X is typically in the range 16 to 96. Visual Studio uses 32. It doesn't help that much for pseudo-random data, with only about a 10% decrease in sort time for large arrays.