# Key comparisons in a merge-insertion hybrid sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge

I was given the task with the merge-insertion sort described as(paraphrased):

> Starting off with merge sort, once a threshold S(small positive integer) is reached, the algorithm will then sort the sub arrays with insertion sort.

We are tasked to find the optimal S value for varying length of inputs to achieve **minimum key comparisons**. I implemented the code by modifying what was available online to get:

```
def mergeSort(arr, l, r, cutoff):
    if l < r:
        m = l+(r-l)//2
        if len(arr[l:r+1]) > cutoff:            
            return mergeSort(arr, l, m, cutoff)+mergeSort(arr, m+1, r, cutoff)+merge(arr, l, m, r)

        else:
            return insertionSort(arr, l, r+1)
    
    return 0

def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    comp = 0
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r - m

    L = [0] * (n1)
    R = [0] * (n2)

    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = arr[l + i]

    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l

    while i < n1 and j < n2:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
        comp +=1

    while i < n1:
        arr[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < n2:
        arr[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
    
    return comp

def insertionSort(arr, l, r):
    comp = 0
    for i in range(l+1, r):
 
        key = arr[i]
 
        j = i-1
        while j >= l:
            if key >= arr[j]:
                comp += 1
                break
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
            comp += 1
        arr[j + 1] = key

    return comp
```

However the graph I get for the minimum value of S against length is:[image]

This means that a near-pure mergesort is almost always preferred over the hybrid. Which is against what is available online, saying that insertion sort will perform faster than mergesort at low values of S(~10-25). I can't seem to find any error with my code, so is hybrid sort really better than merge sort?

Comment: There was an almost-exactly similar question asked a few days ago on this site. The answer given was that your conclusion is correct: if you're only counting the number of key comparisons, merge sort is always better than insertion sort, even on small lists. However, it's true that in practical applications, a hybrid mergesort-insertionsort algorithm is usually faster than merge sort. But the reason is not the number of key comparisons.

Comment: An intuitive reason can be found by trying to sort a deck of cards by hand. If the number of cards is large enough, then you should trust the theory and use merge sort or quicksort (or a more human-suited adaptation). But if the number of cards is small, both mergesort and quicksort become inefficient compared to insertion sort, simply because they're more complicated, and it's not worth the bother for a small number of cards.

Comment: @Stef: a better understanding of the behavior comes by counting not just the comparisons, but also the moves.

Comment: @Stef : Are you referring to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972252/ I think the algorithm implementation is the same but what we are discussing is different. If you are referring to a different question please send me the link and I will delete this question, I don't want to flood this forum with duplicates as well :)

Comment: @tangolin No, I don't remember seeing the question you linked before. I was referring to another. If I find it again I'll link it here.

Comment: @Stef okay sure! Also thanks a lot your comment was very helpful in helping me understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the question is flawed.

Mergesort always performs N Lg(N) key comparisons, while Insertionsort takes N²/2 of them. Hence as of N=2, the comparison count favors Mergesort in all cases. (This is only approximate, as N does not always divide evenly).

But the number of moves as well as the overhead will tend to favor Insertionsort. So a more relevant metric is the *actual running time* which, unfortunately, will depend on the key length and type.

Comment: Although I agree with the overall argument, if you're going to compare the number of comparisons for merge-sort and insertion-sort with an n as small as 2, you should probably use the exact numbers n ⌈lg n⌉ − 2**(⌈lg n⌉) + 1 for merge-sort and n(n-1)/2 for insertion-sort.

Comment: @Stef: as I mentioned, "This is only approximate, as N does not always divide evenly". The important conclusion is that the optimal S is tiny and the count of comparisons is an inappropriate criterion.

Comment: I do agree that this is the important conclusion. But the logic of your first paragraph really sounds wrong to me. You say "Hence as of N=2, the comparison count favors Mergesort in all cases." which sounds completely illogical if you're using two approximate formulae to justify an inequality at N=2. Perhaps an argument like "the comparison count is very close for both algorithms for small N, thus what's important in this situation is not the comparison count, but something else" would make more sense.

Comment: @Stef: I said "This is only approximate, as N does not always divide evenly". This is enough for me.